# Exclude access restricted directory from svn copy

Tags: svn

I need to create a branch from a project in which one directory has somehow restricted access (Do not ask me why and how they did that). When I invoke the svn copy command on the top level directory, it fails because it can't copy the restricted directory.

Is there a way to exclude this directory from svn copy? I do not need it and moreover it is even ignored when I do a checkout of this project.

The only way I see is to invoke svn copy on my working copy and then commit it to the branch. Could this cause problems or is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is really set a restriction on a folder which is needed during the creation of a branch then there is something completely wrong which must be fixed on the server side. 
You can try to create from your working copy a branch via

```
svn copy . URL/branches/B_1 -m"- Branch from WC"
```

Furthermore it's not possible to exclude some folder during the copy while creating a branch.